# How do I import a function contained in a Python egg without installing the module?

Tags: python, egg

Adding a Python `.egg` file to my `PYTHONPATH` does not expose the functions in the `.egg`.

The file structure looks like this

```
eggtest/
├── prime
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── prime.py
├── primetest.py
└── setup.py
```

- `prime.py` contains one function -- `prime` -- that returns true if its argument is prime and false otherwise
- `primetest.py` imports `prime` and tests several integers

After running

```
python setup.py bdist_egg
```

`prime-0.0.0-py2.7.egg` shows up in the newly formed `dist` directory.

The `.egg` should be usable without importing explicitly:

```
PYTHONPATH=dist/prime-0.0.0-py2.7.egg python primetest.py
```

But instead the following errors occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'prime'
```

The function is included in the `.egg`. Why can't the outer Python script import it if the `.egg` is on the path?